# Ошибка свойство WindowsSDKDir не определено. Возможно, не найдены некоторые средства сборки

Tags: c++

Всем хай, при попытки скомпилировать такой код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Human {
private:
    int age;
public:
    void set(int data_age) {
        age = data_age;
    }
    void get() {
        cout << "Hi, i'm Maks" << age << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Human Maks;
    Maks.set(18);
    Maks.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Выбивает с такой ошибкой:warning MSB8003: свойство WindowsSDKDir не определено. Возможно, не найдены некоторые средства сборки.
Я находил методы решения, но они не очень были понятны для меня, может кто объяснить как это пофиксить? Windows 10 x64 visual studio 2019

Comment: ты под дебаг компилировал? у меня была такая проблема. Я просто не указал в path пути до библиотек WindowsSdk

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка обычно вызывается отсутствием нужных средств разработки.

- В установщике Visual Studio следует выбрать для установки целевой Windows SDK на вкладке Отдельные компоненты.
- Проект следует перенацелить на использование целевого SDK. Для этого в контекстном меню решения и проекта в окне Solution Explorer служит пункт Retarget Project.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло